# How to implement, when the reply of a request depends on the reply of another request?

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I am trying to build a hapi project. Here is a `server.route`

```
server.route({ 
    method: ['GET', 'POST'], 
    path: '/login', 
    config: { 
      handler: login, 
    } 
  });
```

The reply of login depends on another request, so I should wait the response of the other request before the login handler ends, right?

Node.js works asynchronously; I am confused as to how I can get the data from the request's response in the handler of login.

Comment: There are many ways to do what you ask. Please provide what you have tried so far.

Comment: Without knowing the specifics the general answer is that the handler function is expected to return a promise.  If you want to make another call then you would do that with a promise and transform the results of that promise before returning from the handler.